# How to add gradient background color in react navigation 6?

Tags: r, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I want to add gradient background color in react navigation header.

In react navigation 5, it has property headerBackground but in RN6 they removed headerBackground.
So how can i add to gradient bg color in header.

Answer (score -1):

Apply gradient to the headerStyle, like on the react navigation docs.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#adjusting-header-styles